# The layout from alert dialog gets messed up with long scrollView

Tags: android, scrollview, alertview

I have an alert dialog which has a custom view. In this view I add checkboxes programmatically. The problem is that when I have like 30 checkboxes in my scroll view, the alert dialog's layout gets messed up. The message falls of the screen and the buttons from the dialog have weird padding.

The first image illustrates the layout that I want. The second one is my problem.
[image: first image with correct layout]
[image: second image with wrong layout]

How can I make sure that the second layout has the same 'header' and 'footer' as the first image?

dialog.xml

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/dialog_filter_brouwerij_linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp">
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Seth the layout_height of the Scrollview to a static dimension?

Comment: is it fragment? or Simple one? Dailog

Comment: @JamesSwinton Static dimensions didn't solve the layout problems for me.

Comment: @DarpanS.Raut, It's a fragment which opens an alert dialog that contains the custom view.

Comment: what i am asking is, is the dailog fragment or simple dialog?

Comment: Oh, it is just a normal simple dialog.